# i use elasticsearch , query dsl and data is below;

Tags: elasticsearch

I use elasticsearch , query dsl  and data is below;  I'm puzzled
    that the score of query "query": "\"the char\" " "  is different 
    with "query": "the char",   can you tell me why?

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "should": [{
            "query_string": {
                "query": "\"the car\"",
                "fields": ["title.ik_gram"],
                "boost": 1.1
            }
        }],
        "disable_coord": false,
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
        "boost": 1.0
    }
}
```

Comment: "query": {
 "bool": {
  "should": [{
   "query_string": {
    "query": "\"the car\"",
    "fields": ["itle.ik_gram"],
    "boost": 1.1
   }
  }],
  "disable_coord": false,
  "adjust_pure_negative": true,
  "boost": 1.0
 }
}

Comment: Its because of the quotation mark. Your first search string is quoted, while the second one is not.

Comment: i explain the dsl ， what is the meaning of ""description": "phraseFreq=1.0","

Comment: `phraseFreq` - is the phrase frequency, which is the number of times the phrase occurs in the content field of the document.